# Django - Method Not Allowed on Function Based View (FBV)

Tags: django, django-views, x-editable

I am getting a `405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED` response when I am trying to submit a POST request through an AJAX call:

`"POST /events/profile_update/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0`

I'm trying to set this up with the most basic view:

```
def profile_update(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        name_form =forms.EventName(request.POST)

        if name_form.is_valid():
            name = name_form.cleaned_data['name']
    else:
        name_form = forms.EventName()

    return render(request, 'event_edit_profile.html', {"name": name})
```

my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/update/$', views.EventProfileUpdateView.as_view(), name='event_profile_update'),
    url(r'^profile_update/$', views.profile_update, name="profile_update"),
]
```

And in my template, I am using [x-editable](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) inline editing to submit the request:

```
<h1 id="name" data-type="text" data-pk="{{ object.id }}" data-url="{% url 'Events:profile_update' %}" data-title="Event Name" data-params="{csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}'}">{{ object.name }}</h1>
```

The request seems to be coming through, and is not being rejected due to CSRF, given that [I don't get a 403](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#rejected-requests), but rather a 405:

```
"POST /events/profile_update/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

For some reason, I can't seem to get past this. Anyone have any ideas as to what could be screwing me up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I broke a basic rule. Here's the fix:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^profile_update/$', views.profile_update, name="profile_update"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/update/$', views.EventProfileUpdateView.as_view(), name='event_profile_update'),
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works. I was struggling with the same issue.